# cargar datagridview segun parametro (procedimiento almacenado)

Tags: c#

Hola buenas tardes a todos, junto con saludarlos nuevamente molestando con una duda: tengo que llenar un datagridview con un procedimiento almacenado de mysql, el cual hace un select y mediante un where limita la consulta:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spMedicamentosPorPaciente` (in textobusqueda varchar (45))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM medicamentos_paciente WHERE idPaciente = textobusqueda  LIMIT 150;
END
```

mi proyecto esta en capas, en la capa datos y negocios tengo un metodo que me permite llenar el grid sin problemas:

```
public DataTable mostrarTabla()
    {
        DataTable dtProfesionales = new DataTable("profesional");

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();

        try
        {
            con.ConnectionString = conexion.cadenaConexion;

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.CommandText = "spMostrarProfesionales";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adaptador.Fill(dtProfesionales);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            dtProfesionales = null;
        }
        return dtProfesionales;

    }
```

y el codigo en negocio:

```
public static DataTable mostrar()
    {
        return new datosProfesional().mostrarTabla();
    }
```

el tema es que no se como hacer para cargar el datatable mostrar con el procedimiento almacenado que tiene el parametro, estoy intentando con este codigo:

```
public DataTable mostrarTabla(datosMedicamentosPaciente medpaciente)
    {
        DataTable dtMedicamentosPaciente = new DataTable("medicamentos_paciente");

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();

        try
        {
            con.ConnectionString = conexion.cadenaConexion;

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.CommandText = "spMedicamentosPorPaciente";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //DECLARAMOS LOS PARAMETROS QUE SON IGUALES A LOS QUE TENEMOS EN EL SP
            MySqlParameter parIdMedPaciente = new MySqlParameter();
            parIdMedPaciente.ParameterName = "@textobusqueda";
            parIdMedPaciente.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parIdMedPaciente.Value = medpaciente.IdMedicamentoPaciente;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parIdMedPaciente);

            MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adaptador.Fill(dtMedicamentosPaciente);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            dtMedicamentosPaciente = null;
        }
        return dtMedicamentosPaciente;

    }
```

en el formulario tengo esta funcion para cargar la grilla:

```
private void cargarGrilla() 
{ 
    this.dgvMedicamentos.DataSource = negocioMedicamentos.mostrar(this.txtCodPaciente.Text); 
    //this.ocultarColumnas(); 
    //lblTotalRegistros.Text = "Total de Registros: " + Convert.ToString(dgvBoxes.Rows.Count); 
}
```

pero me arroja los siguientes errores:

> Error 3   Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'mostrar' toma '1'
>   argumentos.   XXXXXXX\CapaPresentacion\frmMedicamentosPaciente.cs 36  47  CapaPresentacion
>
> Error 4   Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'mostrarTabla' toma '1'
>   argumentos    XXXXXX\CapaNegocios\negocioMedicamentosPaciente.cs  47  20  CapaNegocios

Saludos a todos y gracias

Comment: No me queda claro cual seria el problema...

Comment: listo estimado, adicionado a la pregunta principal

Comment: Ahi el error esta claro.. no estas llamando al mostrarTabla que vos pensas.. estas llamando a otro..

Comment: Me parece que necesitas algo de orden en tu código, basta con hacer un método para llenar un datatable, en la cual reciba un parámetro o si prefieres dos y sobrecargas el método, después de eso basta una línea para llenar el datatable en la capa de presentación, consejo: no es de mucha utilidad que tus métodos sean empleados para un fin único como lo haces, deben ser pensados para ser reutilizados en muchos casos.

Comment: gbianchi, estaba apuntando a datosXX equivocados, ahora lo corregi, no marca error pero no hay carga de datagrid

Comment: @Jorge Luis Alcantara, gracias por tu tiempo, tomare en consideracion tus comentarios, ahora, le paso el parametro en el formulario (metodo cargarGrilla) pero no me muestra nada

Comment: Sí deseas te paso un método a mi manera, con un pequeño detalle, es para SqlServer pero es básicamente lo mismo para MySql, solo poner ctrl + . y cambiar los nombres

Comment: GRACIAS JORGE, COMO PARA GUIARME UN POCO

Comment: ya queda, método con dos parámetros, el procedimiento almacenado y el indice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**En la capa de datos, como método general para retornar un datatable con dos parámetros**

```
namespace Data
{
    public class Connection
    {
        public SqlConnection connectionString = 
        new SqlConnection("Server = XXXXXXX, 1433; Initial Catalog = XXXXX; Persist Security Info=False;User ID = jorgeluis; Password=XXX@XXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout = 30;");

        public void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                connectionString.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        public void Disconnect()
        {
            try
            {
                connectionString.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Acomodas tu mensaje de error en logs, directo al usuario o como prefieras
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace Data
{
    public class ReadGeneralData
    {
        public DataTable GetDataTable(string storedProcedure, string nameColumn1, Int16 id1)
        {
            DataTable dataTable             = new DataTable();
            Connection connection           = new Connection();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand           = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter   = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sqlCommand.CommandText          = storedProcedure;
            sqlCommand.CommandType          = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Connection           = connection.connectionString;
            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand    = sqlCommand;

            SqlParameter parameter1     = new SqlParameter();
            parameter1.SqlDbType        = SqlDbType.SmallInt;
            parameter1.ParameterName    = nameColumn1;
            parameter1.Value            = id1;

            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter1);
            connection.Connect();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            connection.Disconnect();

            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

**En la capa de presentación**

```
    ReadGeneralData readGeneralData = new ReadGeneralData();
    grd.DataSource = 
    readGeneralData.GetDataTable("TU_procedimiento_Almacenado", "nameColumn1", 1));
    // 1 Es un valor referencial, ya ves que valor le pasas, recuerda ajustarlo al tipo de datos 
    // que se declare en la capa de datos
    grd.DataBind(); // En caso de que sea web
```

Comment: gracias jorge, ya tengo adecuado el codigo de la capa datos, ahora, en la capa presentacion me perdi, si quiero utilizarlo para un datagridview? no etiendo esta parte que me compartiste

Comment: El primer parámetro es el nombre del procedimiento almacenado, el segundo es el nombre de la columna en la cual vas a buscar y el tercer p. es el valor asignado, estos dos últimos es para la consulta sql

Comment: si esos estoy ok, aca tengo la duda:  ReadGeneralData readGeneralData = new ReadGeneralData(); en c# me da error de using, y no me aparece info en google

Comment: Ah claro, olvidé decirte que **ReadGeneralData** es el nombre de mi clase de la capa de datos, en tu caso instancia el nombre de tu clase

Comment: Ya ahora si esta super detallado, espero te sirva amigo.

Comment: Muchas gracias jorge, funciono impecable!!! gracias por tu tiempo y por la ayuda